# Difficult change of colum's name in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df - pd.DataFrame({"col1" : [1 ,2 ,3],
                   "col1" : [2,3,4],
                   "col2" : [10, 11, 12]})
```

And then I make: `df.columns.tolist()` and I have list of columns of df:

```
["col1",
 "col1",
 "col2]
```

And how can I change the name of the second "col1" to for example "col3" ? because as I means if I will try: `df.rename(columns={"col1" : "col3"}, inplace=True)` the first "col1" will be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change column name by positions:

```
df.columns.to_numpy()[1] = 'col3'
print (df)
   col1  col3  col2
0     1     2    10
1     2     3    11
2     3     4    12
```

Another idea is deduplicate columns names first:

```
df.columns = pd.io.parsers.ParserBase({'names':df.columns})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)
print (df)
   col1  col1.1  col2
0     1       2    10
1     2       3    11
2     3       4    12
```

So you can use `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"col1.1" : "col3"})
print (df)
   col1  col3  col2
0     1     2    10
1     2     3    11
2     3     4    12
```

Comment: No No No, col1 with values 2,3,4 have to be changed to col3

Comment: @jack55 - Sorry, answer was changed.